# Copying a complete XML Element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am translating one XML file to another.  I want to copy a single, complete element from the original xml into the new xml.  I have tried using the identity transformation but can only get that to work if I copy the entire document.  If I try to limit to just a single element (which contains a lot of data), I get the values of everything in the document - not the xml tags and not just what is in the desired element.  I'm relatively new to XSLT so I'm probably not understanding the identity transformation process correctly.

Here is my sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataExtract Version="1.0">
    <ImportExport>Export</ImportExport>
    <Entities>
        <Entity>
            <Data>UnwantedDataA</Data>
            <Data>UnwantedDataB</Data>
        </Entity>
        <Entity>
            <Data>UnwantedDataC</Data>
            <Data>UnwantedDataD</Data>
        </Entity>
        <Entity>
            <EntityData>
                <Data>ABC</Data>
                <Data>DEF</Data>
                <Data>GHI</Data>
                <SpecialData id="1">Definitely wanted</SpecialData>
            </EntityData>
        </Entity>
    </Entities>
</DataExtract>
```

I want to get the EntityData element and put it out exactly as it is in the input.

If I use the following to copy the entire input document, I get a full duplicate with xml tags, etc.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if I try to only get the EntityData element using the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="EntityData">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the values instead of the xml and for the entire document, not just EntityData:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    Export


            UnwantedDataA
            UnwantedDataB


            UnwantedDataC
            UnwantedDataD


            <EntityData>
                ABC
                DEF
                GHI
                Definitely wanted
            </EntityData>
```

I really want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityData>
    <Data>ABC</Data>
    <Data>DEF</Data>
    <Data>GHI</Data>
    <SpecialData id="1">Definitely wanted</SpecialData>
</EntityData>
```

I've tried different options with copy and copy-of and everything I have read talks about copying the entire document and possibly excluding a few things. I want to exclude everything except the EntityData element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to exclude everything except the EntityData element.

That can be achieved very simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/DataExtract">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Entities/Entity/EntityData"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this assumes there's only one `EntityData` element in the entire input document. Otherwise you will end up with ill-formed XML as the result (not having a single root element).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had tried this approach originally with my real data (which is more complex of course) but it didn't work.  I must have missed something simple and ended up in a completely different direction.  Can you explain why the approach in my sample put out values rather than xml?  I just want to understand what was really going on.

Comment: @sldorman The reason why your output (which BTW **is** XML) contains text values is that you are applying templates to elements which have no template matching them. In such case, the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) kick in - and the default action is to copy the text nodes.